# Cross compiling with Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt

I will ask for a possibility to set a vendor specific toolchain for cross compiling in Eclipse Neon. Is it possible and how to add a custom toolchain?

Another question is how tell the indexer to process additional header files. I see a lot of unresolved references. Adding "User Setting Entries" doesn't work.

Thanks for tips!

Comment: addition: it is a make project